# Permision to list created in new site collectin where user havent got any rights to read

Tags: permissions

I created a sharepoint list in new site collection. How to create a list in new site colection ang give rights only to this list. It can be design, but how to add permision to list not all site, only a list. After I tried to vote on this list I get this sort of error: **access denied. you do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource**

I have got only this sort of permisions[image]

Answer (score 1):

Break permission at list level and provide desired permission to user at list.

Comment: I haven't got this permision limited access

Comment: I made View Only, and this worked.

Comment: Great.. Edited my answer

Comment: But then it don't work. The user can't vote.